# I want to make the categories and series draggable in Ag grid Charts

Tags: ag-grid, ag-charts, ag-charts-react

I am trying to make a ag grid chart where I want to customize the x and y-axis data. So I want that I can drag series into the categories and it should get added in categories.

[image]

Here I want to drag gold into categories. Is there any event for this?

```
`https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=index.jsx&preview`
```

I am looking for an event but unable to find it

Comment: Seems like you've added an empty link.